# How can i get all fields for a selected page Layout using Apex or visualforce page

Tags: apex, page-layout

I have a requirement to get all Fields for a specific Page Layout as per Record Type.

I have searched lot over Google about any API/Apex related with page Layout but unfortunately not found any helpful post.

Answer (score 2):

The Metadata API allows layouts to be accessed. See this example [MetadataServiceExamples](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/65edbf6be9a00cd5e16173ac7dffe223b76cdd3f/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L868) from the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) project for how to use this API from Apex.

Not that each API call is a web service call and so you need to be careful to not make the call from a context that does not allow web service calls. Also the volume of code is large, so if that is a problem you will need to remove the classes for the many API calls you are not making.